# Separate strings in a string with Actionscripts3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to separate two part of a string, one is Title one is Value, RegExp is confused  me. I need your help to solve this thanks

```
var pattern2:RegExp = new RegExp("TZ_NUM_ANSWER:Telegram code([0-9.-]+)");//TZ_NUM_ANSWER:Telegram code 32263
       var data2:Object = pattern2.exec(response);
       if (data2 != null && data2[1] != null) 
       {
         var value2:Number = parseFloat(data2[1]);
         trace("TZ_NUM_ANSWER  " + value2);
         txt_BUY1.text = String(value2);
       }
```

Output:

```
TZ_NUM_ANSWER:Telegram code 32263
```

It must be:

```
"TZ_NUM_ANSWER:" "Telegram code 32263"
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't try [split](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split())?

Comment: The reason is because I'm new developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use RegEx for simple stuff. All you need is basic string methods:

```
response.split(":");
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of *split* is an **Array** you can access to **Array** **indexes** and assign them to a variable.

```
var STR1:String = "TZ_NUM_ANSWER:Telegram code 32263";

var STR2:String;

var STR3:String;

trace(STR1.split(":"));

STR2 = STR1.split(":")[0];
STR3 = STR1.split(":")[1];

trace (STR2);
trace (STR3);
```

Result:

```
TZ_NUM_ANSWER
Telegram code 32263
```